# Can a dagger be used as a melee weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, weapons

In the PHB1, daggers are indicated to be light-thrown weapons. But is it possible to use them also for melee attacks against adjacent opponents? That seems to be logistically possible, but I am not sure if the rules allow it. Also, if it is possible, is it a strength or dexterity attack?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Dagger is also listed under simple melee weapons. It's a Strength-based attack.

Answer (score 8):

Daggers are definitely a one handed melee weapon in D&D 4th Edition. Players Hanbook 1 page 218 lists a dagger as a "Simple Melee Weapon" sub category one-handed.

Stats for the plain dagger are as follows:

> Dagger: +3 Proficiency; 1d4 Damage; 5/10 squares Range (if thrown); 1gp Price; 1 pound Weight; light blade Weapon Group; has the off-hand and light thrown Properties.

While a specific class attack will tell you what skill bonus to use (such as Dexterity for a Rogue's Deft Strike) a basic attack with melee weapons would be Strength vs. Armor Class. Basic ranged attacks use Dexterity. Therefore, if you are just stabbing with a dagger (and not using a class specific maneuver) it's STR v AC and if you are throwing the dagger it's DEX v AC.